# Every element in a local ring is either invertible or nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

I would like to ask about the correctness of [the proof of 2.4. Proposition.](https://csmj.mosuljournals.com/article_163734_5918040e97a74ae60df25949d4144918.pdf) I think it is not true. This proposition is stated as follows:

> Let $R$ be a local ring. Then, every element in $R$ is either invertible or nilpotent.

*Proof.* Let $a$ be a non-invertible element in $R$. Then, $1-a$ is invertible since $R$ is a local ring, so there exists $u\in R$ such that $(1-a)u=1$ **and that can be held when $u=1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{n-1}\in R$.** Then, $a^n=0$, so $a$ is nilpotent.

I think the bold line is wrong. Any counterexample or reference or technique is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This "paper" is not properly TeXed, the spelling and grammar is abysmal and, most importantly, many of the claims in there are absurdly wrong, including this one. I would advise to stay far away from it. To obtain something funny, if the proposition in question were true, combining it with Lemma 2.7 (which happens to be right as it's just quoted from elsewhere) suddenly implies all local rings are $0$-dimensional.

Comment: Whoever translate that book/article  to English did a terrible terrible job.

Comment: Perhaps the author confused the nilradical and the Jacobson radical.

Comment: As written, the results (that are not cited from other resources) are incorrect (something like 90% of this type) or utterly trivial (E.g. Prop 2.8, 2.13).  I can't find any results cited from other texts that are incorrect, but those citations given are generally very basic material, and they only serve to support the trivial propositions.  I won't speculate on the origin of the mistakes, but I would also advise not giving the paper further attention, and to be on the lookout for similar ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, this proof is nonsense and the proposition is false. An easy counterexample is the ring $k[[x]]$ of formal power series over a field $k$, with unique maximal ideal $(x)$; we can take $a = x$ and then $1 - x$ is invertible with inverse $1 + x + x^2 + \dots $ but $x$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: It should be true if in addition you assume that $R$ is Artinian.